# Написание своего Vocal Pitch Monitor

Tags: c#, naudio

Существует программа под названием Vocal Pitch Monitor

Как следует из названия, эта программа дает фидбек по высоте голоса -- ее часто используют для тренировки вокальных навыков.

Встречали ли вы информацию как сделать такую же апликуху?

Это должно быть довольно просто по-логике.

[image: Vocal Pitch Monitor]

Comment: Интересная тема.Между занятиями по гитаре беру уроки вокала и эти программы стоят у меня на телефоне. Сам подумывал о том, чтобы написать подобную программу: мне правда нужно ещё вывести минус и показать эталонную вокальную партию (подобное умеет Sing Sharp, но собственные треки имеют непонятный формат). У меня есть некоторый набор популярных статей на эти тематики, но готового пошагового how to не встречал.

Comment: @AK, вот и я хочу написать что то вроде  Sing Sharp :) Только немного другое.